# Asynchrony issue with react in a raspberry Pi and slow stuttering connection

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, raspberry-pi

I have an issue on the access page. I have running on the Raspberry the 5 micros and the frontend (using react). The issue is that whenever I turn on the thing, the front loads first, then the micros finish launching and every time i see a stuttering as if the state variable "loading" was changing from true to false and then back to true, back to false... it does this blinking thing a few times then it works just fine. The thing is that i cant replicate it in local testing and i dont understand why. I've tried launching the front first and then launching the micros one by one and still get no stuttering in the laptop. i cant understand why i'm getting it in the raspberry. the calls in the raspberry are still being done "locally", no internet involved, so the slow connection shouldn't matter. plus, when using a raspberry in developer mode, like in my laptop, running everything with some npm run dev, i get no blinking.
this is the pertinent code.

The action function:

```
export function getBackendStatusAction() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      let errorOccurred = false;

      const fetchStatus = async (endPoint) => {
        try {
          const res = await apiFetch('GET', { endPoint });
          return res.status;
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      };

      const endpoints = ['iam/status', 'administration/status', 'evaluations/status', 'mqtt/status', 'logs/status'];
      const results = await Promise.all(endpoints.map((endPoint) => fetchStatus(endPoint)));

      results.forEach((status) => {
        if (status !== 200) {
          errorOccurred = true;
          dispatch(backendOffline());
        }
      });

      if (!errorOccurred) {
        dispatch(backendOnline());
      }

      if (errorOccurred) {
        setTimeout(() => getBackendStatusAction()(dispatch), 5000);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(backendOffline());
    }
  };
}
```

And where the code is called:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { loginActions, loadingAction } = this.props;
    loadingAction(true);
    loginActions.getBackendStatusAction();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { loginError, backendStatus, loadingAction } = this.props;
    const { showModal } = this.state;
    if (prevProps.backendStatus !== backendStatus) {
      loadingAction(!backendStatus);
    }
    if (loginError !== '' && loginError !== undefined && showModal === false) {
      this.handleShowModal(loginError);
    }
  }
```

Can you please help me?